# Cordova Authentication

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have this error why trying to log in to my Cordova/Ionic app.

```
Cannot read property 'error_description' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'error_description' of undefined
at http://localhost:8000/js/services/Authentication.js:39:32
at processQueue (http://localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21888:27)
at http://localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21904:27
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23100:28)
at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22916:31)
at ChildScope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23205:24)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30139:23)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4430:9)
at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4116:28)
at triggerMouseEvent (http://localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2863:7)
```

I need to know, does my login/pass are wrong, or Just my app doesn't work

Authentication related code is

```
          doLogin:         function (username, password) {
 return ServerAPI.logIn({}, {Username: username, Password: password, Version: AppConstants.Build, grant_type: "password"}).$promise
      .then(function (response) {
        if (!response.error) {
          authService.loginCancelled({});
          currentUser.isAuthenticated = !response.error;
          currentUser.data = response;
          currentUser.data.UserId = response.currentUserId;
          currentUser.data.UserName = username;
          currentUser.UserId = response.currentUserId;
          currentUser.lastloggedinTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
          // Saves session data into database so it can be accessed after app reopened
          Database.insertInto('Session', currentUser.UserId, currentUser, {});
          // Saves the session data into a cookie so the request interceptor can access it
          Session.put('emInspectionUser', currentUser);
          authService.loginConfirmed(currentUser);
        }
        else {
          Session.remove('emInspectionUser');
        }
        return response;
      }, function (error) {
        if (error.status === 0) {
          return $q.reject('Could not connect to server.\nPlease check your network connection.');
        }
        else if (error.data.error_description) {
          return $q.reject(error.data.error_description);
        }
        return $q.reject(error.status + ': ' + error.statusText);
      });
```

I'm running cordova app and I have login and pass, but I'm not sure that my login and pass are correct, and I Can not test that, because of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your else if condition as follow

```
else if (error.data.hasOwnProperty(error_description)) {
    return $q.reject(error.data.error_description);
}
```